# MAMP - phpMyAdmin - Error

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Quando vou entrar no phpMyAdmin atraves no Mamp, dá este erro:

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>   Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR)) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Alguém me pode ajudar ?

Comment: Tem que dar permissão na pasta, acredito eu.

Comment: Ola Obrigado, qual pasta?

Comment: Linux ou Windows você está utlizando ?

Comment: Ola no  IOS (MAC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim pelo terminal em Applications.:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /Applications/MAMP/tmp/
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54281/discussion-on-answer-by-diego-souza-mamp-phpmyadmin-error)

Comment: Depois de 3 meses você vai fazer isso ? @bigown Lamentável.